# MySQL Installation error: Unable to update security settings

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, windows, installation

I tried to configure MySQL server 5.5 on Windows and this is what I got:

```
mysql-server-5.5-winx64:56 - Attempting to update security settings. 
mysql-server-5.5-winx64:100 - Unable to update security settings. Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts. 
mysql-server-5.5-winx64:62 - Attempting to verify command-line client shortcut.
```

Any thoughts? I found [this article](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,419964,431649#msg-431649) on it, but I'm not really sure what to do. I tried getting random processes to work but it didn't seem to change much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with root access and firewall.

To fix this I:

1. Ran it on a machine with full root acces
2. Added all MySQL items to
   firewall list and ran reconfiguration of the MySQL

Ability to access root is important. I tried repeating this on a machine were I do not have root access and failed on every attempt

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the product in a new undefined library.  Once that was done, the install did not ask for the original root password and installed without error.